# Why can a Task be associated with a CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, task

Can someone explain why a Task can be instantiated with a CancellationToken?

To be clear, here I'm not talking about what is a CancellationToken and what it is made for, my question is really «what is a Task doing with an optionally provided CancellationToken?

```cs
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
    }
}, cts.Token);

cts.Cancel(); // This cancel will never cancel anything, so what can a task do with a CancellationToken?
```

Comment: The documentation for the method tells you exactly what it does...

Comment: It controls whether the Task returned from Task.Run is marked as Cancelled or Faulted, if an exception is throw from that CancellationToken

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the  [Task constructor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task__ctor_System_Action_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) do not explain the purpose of the CancellationToken...

Comment: @Kino101 But you're not calling the task constructor.  You're calling `Task.Run`.

Comment: True, when I wrote the question I was watching the Task constructor, but when I wrote the code, I preferred writing Task.Run() as this is the most common way of creating tasks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for that particular overload of `Task.Run` explicitly and clearly states:

> A cancellation token that can be used to cancel the work if it has not yet started. `Run(Action, CancellationToken)` does not pass `cancellationToken` to `action`.

Tasks are not "created with" or "associated with" cancellation tokens.

So it's only used as an early out. If you give to `Task.Run` a token that's already cancelled, nothing is scheduled and an already cancelled task is returned. Similarly, if it becomes cancelled by the moment the task is ready to run, the resulting task will get cancelled.

Cancellation in .NET is always cooperative, not preemptive: the task's function is responsible for checking the token itself once it has begun.

Comment: Didn't downvote. I'd note, also, that if the thread pool is busy, that cancellation token can also become cancelled after `Task.Run`, but before the task is scheduled and it'll similarly avoid wasting time on actually scheduling it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good point, I'll clarify that.

Comment: Thanks Etienne, this is clear (I read the documentation for the Task constructor, not the Task.Run method :/)